# Pandas groupby stored in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Bank','GSE','PSE'],
            'Sub Cat':['Tier1','Small','Small', 'Small'],
            'Location':['US','US','UK','UK'],
            'Amount':[50, 55, 65, 55],
            'Amount1':[1,2,3,4]})

df2=df1.groupby(['Counterparty','Location'])[['Amount']].sum()
df2.dtypes
df1.dtypes
```

The df2 data frame does not have the columns that I am aggregating across ( Counterparty and Location). Any ideas why this is the case ? Both Amount and Amount1 are numeric fields. I just want to sum across Amount and aggregate across Amount1

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For columns from index add `as_index=False` parameter or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2=df1.groupby(['Counterparty','Location'])[['Amount']].sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
  Counterparty Location  Amount
0         Bank       US     105
1          GSE       UK      65
2          PSE       UK      55

df2=df1.groupby(['Counterparty','Location'], as_index=False)[['Amount']].sum()
print (df2)
  Counterparty Location  Amount
0         Bank       US     105
1          GSE       UK      65
2          PSE       UK      55
```

If aggregate by all columns here happens [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns) - column `Sub Cat` is omitted:

```
df2=df1.groupby(['Counterparty','Location']).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
  Counterparty Location  Amount  Amount1
0         Bank       US     105        3
1          GSE       UK      65        3
2          PSE       UK      55        4


df2=df1.groupby(['Counterparty','Location'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: It is always nice to add `.reset_index()`.

Comment: worked with the .reset_index(). Will have to read up on why .reset_index() is needed !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double brackets around the `'Amount'` and make them single brackets. You're telling it to only select one column.